# A problem about git flow continously merge bugfix branch into dev branch

Tags: git, merge, conflict

[gitFlow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfoLl.png)

I'm confused about the continuously merge from `bugfix` branch to `dev` branch of `gitflow`. Think about this situation, if there are conflict when i merge commit `A` and `B` into `dev` branch, and i resolved it. Then i do several commits in `bugfix` branch, and now if i merge `bugfix` branch into `dev` branch, did i need to resolve the conflict caused by commit `A` and `B` again?

I know git find the same ancestor commit to perform a 3-way compare, and if i guess right, the same ancestor commit will always be the yellow commit, so i need to resolve same conflict again and again when continuously merge `bugfix` into `dev`, this is unreasonable. I also verify my guess, but the results is inconsistent.

Could anybody help me, thanks very much!

**update**: my test detail:
[log graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWvqN.png)

The test shows the git merge algorithm look likes can remember my resolve in commit `D` and auto resolve conflict sometimes. I know it may hard to explain about the test, but i would be grateful if anyone could tell me what did the git merge algorithm do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drawing is wrong. There must be no long lived bug fix branch. You merge C into dev to form D, now you *delete* that branch. If someone wants to make E, it branches from dev, not C.

(Either that or keep reverse merging dev into bugfix just before each merge into dev.)

Comment: Thanks! I completely agree with you about we need delete the `bugfix` or reverse merge `dev` into `bugfix`, and that's what I've always done. But now i wanted to use [gitFlow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html), and then i found its `release branches` with bugfix need continously merge into `dev`, the graph shows we neither delete `release branches` nor merge back into `release branches` every time(unless a new version need release).

Comment: So i did the above test, and i get the result that we may need reslove the same conflict again and again sometimes, that is ridiculous for the gitFlow. So i want to know if it is the gitflow's defect, or git can auto merge this situation with some merge algorithm?

Comment: my test indicate that is the gitflow's defect, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Any time you have two long lived branches and you merge in only one direction between them, you risk repeated merge conflicts. If you read the original git flow article, he expects a conflict on every release because of the increased build number. It's not a flaw, it's just what you get for having long lived branches.

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer resolved my doubts!

Answer (score 0):

in a `merge`, individual revisions that make up the history of the branches that are being merged is not important. Git will find the last common ancestor (not really in `recursive` strategy, but alas, good for explaining) and will compare the *tips of the branches* being merged with this revision. If the differences of those branches against the common ancestor can't be merged together then you get a conflict (or many). If A or B generated conflicts at some point in the history of any of the branches is actually irrelevant at that point.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! You answer is make sense, i do some test and will post the test detail later, the brief as follow:

f
|\
| e
d |
|\|
b c
|/
a

I firstly merge `b` and `c` into `d` (resolve conflict), then i push commit `e` to `bugfix` and merge to `dev`, the conflict sometimes will not appear, it look likes the git remember my resolve sometimes.

I know it may hard to explain, i would be grateful if you could tell me what did the git merge really do? Or in other words, if i merge from `bugfix` to `dev` several times like the test, will the same conflict appear?